# Opera & Firefox focus issue on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having a strange problem with my Jquery UI Dialog in opera. In all other browser the code works fine, including IE 8, but for some reason in Opera I have to use the tab button to select a field inside my dialog. I can't use my mouse to select a field!

Update: I have this issue with Firefox as well! So it wasn't just opera. It definitely works fine in Chrome & IE. I can't select any of my input fields. Anybody know how I can get normal focussing back on my html elements?

```
//Build the dialog
    function createActivityDialog() {
        var dropdown, activitydialog, timepicker, i, stageid;

        timepicker = "<select name='dialogbegintime' id='dialogbegintime'>";
        for ( i = 0; i < $("#times li").length; i = i + 1) {
            timepicker += "<option value='time" + i + "'>" + hourArray[i] + ":00" + "</option>";
        }
        timepicker += "</select>";

        dropdown = "<select name='podia' id='podia'>";
        for ( i = 0; i < $(".tr").length; i = i + 1) {
            stageid = $(".tr").eq(i).attr("id");
            dropdown += "<option value='" + stageid + "'>" + $(".th").eq(i).html() + "</option>";
        }
        dropdown += "</select>";

        activitydialog = $('<div></div>').html("<p id='dialogTip'>Voer hier een nieuwe activiteit in:</p><br />" + "Naam: <input type='text' name='activityName' id='activityName' /><br />" + "Selecteer een begintijd:" + timepicker + "<br />Selecteer het podium: " + dropdown).dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            title : 'Activiteit Toevoegen',
            height : 300,
            width : 350,
            modal : true,
            close : function() {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        return activitydialog;
    }

//Call/Open the dialog

$("#SomeForm").submit(function(event) {
    var mydialog;
    mydialog = createActivityDialog();
    mydialog.dialog('open');
    mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons", [{
        text : "Ok",
        click : ActivityDialogOk
    }, {
        text : "Cancel",
        click : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="SomeForm" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="addActivity">
        Add
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please, can you provide your HTML and function call?
You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ service and post here a link.

Comment: I was trying to put it on js fiddle, but jquery ui dialog doesnt really work there it seems. Also, I seem to have reached a character limit in my question.

Comment: //html

<form id="SomeForm" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="addActivity">
     Add
    </button>
</form>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZY5Vs/9/ — here I just tried to predict what is your code and JS. jQuery UI dialog would work if you check appropriate  checkbox in jsFiddle.
Also this jsFiddle code works fine in Firefox, so maybe there is a problem somewhere else?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/judCG/ - i tried this but i get some errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pXPGZ/ — Here, I fixed these errors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I figured where is the problem: `$(document).disableSelection();` — comment this out and all will work fine.

jQuery UI dialog opens first tabbable element so first input is focused, but due `disableSelection` on whole document causes that you can't focus field with mouse.

Comment: I would have liked to keep the page selection disabled though, it's a cool feature. I'll have to look into it.